# Are there handles to the mainWindow's dock splitters?

Tags: qt

Is it possible to return a handle to the splitters in `QMainWindow` which separate the dock widgets?

Comment: What do you mean by a handle?

Comment: a pointer/method/etc which allows me to operate on them or determine their state.

Comment: got it. and what are the dock widgets? toolbars? or mdi windows? could you make a screenshot of a splitter? I can't fully understand what elements do you mean.

Answer (score 0):

There is some internal class QMainWindowLayout, maybe you can figure out how to get to it if you look into [source](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/57756e72adf2081137b97f0e689dd16c770d10b1:src/gui/widgets/qmainwindowlayout.cpp)

I personally don't think you can get handle to it.. I don't know what you want to achieve - the handle can be styled with QMainWindow::separator..

But you can try to use QSplitter which has method QSplitter::handle(index). You can then add some buttons to the handle etc:

```
button = new QPushButton("<", ui->splitter->handle(1));
handleLayout->addWidget(button);
ui->splitter->handle(1)->setLayout(handleLayout);
```

I was experimenting with QDockWidget in QSplitter's layout and it was working.